# Unable to view errored certificate

Tags: internet-explorer, certificate

Does anyone know how to view the certificate when a non-bypassable security error occurs in Internet Explorer version 11?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e0ec4417-02cd-4670-ba4a-fcb57e0327d6/unable-to-view-ssl-certificate-in-ie11?forum=ieitprocurrentver wasn't much help.

I've included an example screenshot below:

[image]

In this particular case, Google Chrome was installed so I used that to determine why the security error was non-bypassable (HSTS preventing downgrade attacks) and what the cause was (RMM agent seemed to be messing up the certificate, probably due to the SANs) but I'd like to know for the future.

Comment: Does the same problem happen with Edge? Why are you still running IE?

Comment: @Spiff The same happened with Google Chrome so the cause was browser-unspecific. The reason for using IE is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the below openssl command to check which certificate was installed for the specified URL

**openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -showcerts**

Comment: I posted my own answer but I've marked yours as accepted as it's browser-agnostic and outputs a lot more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've since read that typing "badidea" into Google Chrome will bypass even HSTS certificate errors.

I've verified that this works with https://subdomain.preloaded-hsts.badssl.com.